# The rate of convergence of the remainder of the power series for the Polylog function

Tags: sequences-and-series, polylogarithm, rate-of-convergence

Let $0<p<1$ be a positive real number strictly smaller than one and $q>0$ be a positive real number. Consider the series
$$
\mathsf{Li}_{-q}(p) = \sum_{\ell=1}^{+\infty}\ell^{q}p^{\ell}
$$
which defines the polylogarithmic function. Is there any result on the rate at which the remainder
$$
c_n=\sum_{\ell=n}^{+\infty}\ell^{q}p^{\ell}
$$
goes to zero? My guess is $c_n=O(n^q\,p^n)$, but I cannot find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{c_n}{n^q p^n}\underset{\ell=n+k}{\quad=\quad}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k\left(1+\frac kn\right)^q\quad\color{blue}{\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}}\quad\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k=\frac1{1-p}$$ by [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) (with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k(1+k)^q$ being the dominating convergent series).